# How to count unique common values between groups using SQL or Tableau?

Tags: python, unique, tableau-api, powerquery

I am unable to figure out a way to count unique common values between groups using Power Query, SQL, or Tableau.

INPUT: I have a dataset like this:

```
Group   Value
A   1
A   2
A   3
A   4
A   5
B   3
B   5
B   6
B   7
C   8
C   3
C   6
C   9
```

OUTPUT: I want a symmetric matrix giving the count of unique values between different group combinations

```
    A   B   C   Total Unique
A   5   2   1   5
B   2   4   1   4
C   1   1   4   4
```

I tried using pivot tables after creating a helper COUNTIF column but couldn't solve my problem. Also, my dataset has more than 2M rows.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to me that C/B is =1 when they share both 3 and 6, which seems to indicate should be =2

That said, below is some powerquery which appears to do what I think you want. However merging 2 million rows on top of itself is likely going to make powerquery choke, but give it a try. I'd recommend another tool

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(Source),
Distinct = Table.Group(#"Removed Duplicates", {"Group"}, {{"Distinct", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Removed Duplicates", {"Value"}, #"Removed Duplicates", {"Value"}, "Changed Type", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Changed Type" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Changed Type", {"Group"}, {"Group2"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Changed Type",{"Value"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", each 1),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Added Custom", List.Distinct(#"Added Custom"[Group2]), "Group2", "Custom", List.Sum),
#"Merged Queries1" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Pivoted Column", {"Group"}, Distinct, {"Group"}, "aaa", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
Expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries1", "aaa", {"Distinct"}, {"Distinct"})
in  Expanded
```

[image]